# Spring data spa query incorrect parsing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot 3.0.4 and native query with interface based projections https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html#projections.interfaces
and this `Optional<Set<String>> getValue();` method in interface. Query simply gets the column value from db without any modifications.
In database corresponding column saved in jsonb format as array of strings
In entity this column looks like

```
    @Type(io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType.class)
        @Column(name = "value", columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
        private Set<String> value = new HashSet<>();
```

after update to spring boot 3.2.0 I have an incorrect result of native query
expected: ["value1", "value2"]
but was: ["["value1", "value2"]"]
as jpa provider we use - hibernate

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to parse the String with `JsonParser`
, for example:

```
public List<Object> parseJsonStringToList(String[] value){
        String jsonString = value[0];
        return JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser().parseList(jsonString);
    }
```

calling the function converts *["["value1", "value2"]"]* to *["value1", "value2"]*

*reference:* https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/json/JsonParser.html